# I have created a simple calculator. But it has a large sized application?Very large for a bsic calculator?

Tags: android, apk

I have used appcompatv7 library to add ActionBar. There are no graphics added just the default launcher icon. I am targeting android 4.4. Is there any way I can reduce the size of the application after install, because it is 4.32MB on my 4.2.2 android phone.
When I move it completely to Phone memory, its size is 1.95MB. when installed on SD card its size is 4.32MB. The calculator apk has size of 696kb.

Comment: what is the size of icon?

Comment: I edited the question a bit 24.1 kb in xxhdpi.

Comment: Have you write many files ,for example,sharedperenference.xml?

Comment: Thanx that explained it well